# What happens to messages in Kafka buffer.memory if application got crashed?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, buffer

According to default buffer memory is 32 MB. So may be due to network fluctuation data stored in Buffer memory. So, what happens to the data if server down? and how to re generate the data from buffer memory?

Since it is buffer memory if application or server goes down then data will be lost. So how to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If a Kafka broker goes pop then any data not written to disk, i.e. any data still only in memory, is lost.

However, that's only taking into account 1 Kafka broker. Kafka provides fault tolerance / resiliency by running multiple Kafka brokers and replicating data across them.

I'd suggest reading up on this if you want to understand this more.  Just search the web for "Kafka fault tolerance resiliency" and you'll find plenty of posts going into it in great depth.